# Uncaught TypeError: root is undefined papaparse

Tags: javascript, typeerror, papaparse

I have a problem with `papaparse` in my code, I try to parse a string but is giving me this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: root is undefined"

the code is like:

```js
import * as Papa from "../file/papaparse/papaparse.js";
input.onchange = e => {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsText(file, 'UTF-8');
  reader.onload = readerEvent => {
    let imported = readerEvent.target.result;
    let splittedimp = this.$Papa.parse(imported, {
      "header": true
    })
    console.log(splittedimp);
  }
}
```

the `input.onchange` is inside an async function.
any idea why this error?
The error happen in papaparse file, line 25:
`root.Papa = factory();`
also i didn't use nodejs or jquery, i have simply downloaded the file and imported it into a folder in my project

Comment: Are you sure the error happens in the shown code?

Comment: It happen in papaparse, line 25 
root.Papa = factory();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that papaparse didn't like the `import as`. I have added the URL into the script in the HTML page connected to the JS page and now works fine.